# TextBox ScrollBar Not Showing After Customization

Tags: c#, wpf

I designed my custom WPF TextBox as follows.

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Name="txtResult" Padding="8" FontFamily="Consolas" Margin="5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                <TextBox.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBox Margin="4" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Text}" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"/>
                            <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}" StrokeThickness="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </TextBox.Template>
            </TextBox>
```

But even after adding the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"` or wrapping the TextBox in `ScrollViewer`, my scrollbars don't show. 
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your `ControlTemplate`'s target already is a `TextBox`, so there should be no reason for the `ControlTemplate` to contain another `TextBox`. Therefore, it could be replaced by a `ScrollViewer` as a corresponding content host.
Based on that, your `TextBox` could look like this:

```
<TextBox VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
         Name="txtResult"
         Padding="8"
         FontFamily="Consolas"
         Margin="5"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
         TextWrapping="Wrap">
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              BorderThickness="0" 
                              IsTabStop="False" 
                              Margin="4"
                              Background="{x:Null}"/>
                <Rectangle  Stroke="{StaticResource ResourceKey=detailMarkBrush}"
                            StrokeThickness="0"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

If you want to use this template on several `TextBoxes`, I'd recommend a separate style for that.

(Is there a reason that your rectangle has a `StrokeThickness` of 0?)

Comment: I referred to the question's XAML and therefore used the control template to illustrate a permanently visible scrollbar. I agree that just for that there's no reason to use an adjusted template, but for some specific adjustments there's no way around it